# Rotation number for multicomponent Schrödinger equation

Tags: ergodic-theory, schrodinger-operators, stability, almost-periodic-function

Rotation number for Schrödinger equation of the form
\begin{equation}
-x''(t) +q(t) x(t) = E x(t)
\end{equation}

was defined in R. Johnson J. Moser "[The rotation number for almost periodic potentials](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01205510)" as
\begin{equation}
\phi = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\arg(x'(t)+i x(t))}{t}.
\end{equation}

It is related to the asymptotics of zeros of $x(t)$. More importantly, it is used in the stability and bifurcation analysis of the equation. In particular, there is KAM-like analysis of the equation, which exhibits Arnold-like tongues as a function of parameters.

Question: How to define rotation number(s) for the multicomponent Schrodinger equation of the form

\begin{equation}
i\frac{df_a}{dt} = \sum_b H(t)_{a,b}f_b?
\end{equation}

We can assume that the $n$-dimensional matrix $H$ is Hermitian, so the dynamics happens on the unit sphere.

I am not sure, but it may be easier to generalize Lyapunov exponents, rather than rotation number.

I do not know what was the original definition of Lyapunov's exponents for Schrödinger operators, but they are used in a number of recent papers:

1. J. Puig C. Simo  "[Analytic families of reducible linear quasi-periodic differential equations](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0143385705000362)"
2. D. Damanik "[Lyapunov Exponents and Spectral Analysis of Ergodic Schrödinger Operators: A Survey of Kotani Theory and its Applications](https://doi.org/10.1090/pspum/076.2/2307747)"
3. V.A. Chulaevsky and Ya. G. Sinai "[Anderson Localization for the 1-D Discrete Schrödinger Operator with Two-Frequency Potential](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01217771)"

Rotation number in 2d has a clear geometric interpretation. Is it possible to come up with a geometric interpretation in higher dimensions?

EDIT:

As per comment of Prof. C. Remling, the situation is not completely analogous. The question is: what is the best analogy that one can define for rotation  numbers and Lyapunov exponents ( which are tightly related in this case, although I do not know the precise statement) for the above system? "Best" in the following sense. I would like to detect numerically Arnold tongues in the parameter space of the system ( particularly, when H(t) is almost periodic $ = poly(cos(\omega_a t+\phi_a))$). In the refs rotation number was used for this purpose to obtain comprehensive plots, reproduced below.

It seems the rotation number in higher dimensions, even in the case of torus, is ill defined. As discussed in the references given below. Indeed, rotation number is a property of $Diff(S^1)$. So it seems that it does not make sense to look for rotation number for general Hamiltonians.

However, it is true that there are Arnold tongues in the system. It seems the question should be reformulated as:

{\bf Question2:} Which quantity can be used to study the location of Arnold tongues in the parameter space of the system?

I believe there are KAM tori in the system. The boundaries of tongues correspond to destruction of tori. Or their bifurcation ( as discussed by Persival, and MacKay in 80's). But I do not know which quantity I could use to detect this breakdown numerically. I do not know how to numerically recognize the tori in this system. Lyapunov exponents seem to be of no use here, except for vanishing of some of them inside the tori, and being nonzero outside.

Remark1:

answering Prof. C. Remling's comment, there is some analogy. Namely, the Johnson-Moser system can be rewritten as
\begin{gather}
\frac{dx_i}{dt} = \sum_{j=1,2} P_{i,j}(t) x_j(t) ,i=1,2
\end{gather}
for some real polynomials $P_{i,j}$. This is all that is needed to define rotation number.

My system can also be rweritten as
\begin{gather}
\frac{dx_i}{dt} = \sum_j p_{i,j}(t) x_j(t)
\end{gather}

I am mostly interested in the almost periodic case where
\begin{gather}
p_{i,j}(t) = poly(cos(\omega_a t+\phi_a))
\end{gather}
This is the system treated in the paper by Puig,Simo, cited above, for d=2, using rotation number. I believe this provides certain analogy.

Refs on rotation number in higher dim

A. Norton and D. Sullivan. Wandering domains and invariant conformal
structures for mappings of the 2-torus. Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn. Math., 21 (1977),
1996, 51–68.

A symbolic representation for Anosov–Katok systems
Matthew Foreman & Benjamin Weiss

[[image: <span class=]$x''+(a+b(cos(t)+cos(\sqrt{2}t)+cos(\sqrt{3}t))x=0$ Lyapunov exponents as function of parameters for the system. From "Resonance tongues in the quasi-periodic Hill-Schrödinger equation with three frequencies." by    Joaquim Puig & Carles Simo" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdFhq.png)

Comment: You seem to have two questions; it is better to have one question per post.  If you believe that these questions are best together, then you should clearly indicate that there are two questions—I almost missed it after the list of references.

Comment: Your setting is not really analogous to the original one, which starts with the *stationary* equation $Hx=Ex$, $Hx=-x''+qx$, while you consider the time-dependent Schrodinger equation $i\dot{f}=Hf$, or a generalized version of it.

Comment: @ChristianRemling You are right. Please see the edit.